# How to launch external app by Autoit lib using robotframework

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework, autoit, sikuli

have setup Robotframework for Desktop app

1. Its working fine for calculator and Notepad++ to launch app
2. tried to launch external app but its going launch after that app automatically closed before uping app

code:

```
hereLibrary           
AutoItLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
   Test1
    [Tags]    test1
    Run    C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Platform Flash 
    Tool\\platformflashtool.exe
    Wait For Active Window    Intel® Platform Flash Tool 5.8.10.0

    Calc_TC
    [Tags]    Notepad
    Run    C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe
    Wait For Active Window    new 1 - Notepad++
```

Comment: Are there any errors displayed?

Comment: `tried to launch external app but its going launch after that app automatically closed before uping app` - this phrase makes no sense. Please rephrase into proper english. What is an `external app` (or internal one)? What is `uping`? What do you mean by `automatically closed` - by itself? or it seems like it crashes?